# UITableViewController with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to tableView in UITableViewController add a UIPanGestureRecognizer
but if I add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // code
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = nil;
    gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    gestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    // code      
}
```

then the whole table does not respond to any gesture, except one - my
for example: not to scroll gesture

is whether it  possible to solve this problem for to UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right you want the table view to be scrollable but still recognize the pan gesture right?

Have you tried implementing this method from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
    return YES;
}
```